# Accessing data from callback function

Tags: javascript

```
  let toggleForm = function() {
    // code here
  }

  document.getElementById('one').addEventListener("click", toggleForm, false);

  document.getElementById('two').addEventListener("click", toggleForm, false);
```

In toggleForm I'd like to know whether element one or two fired the event. How would you go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `e.target`:

```
<button id = 'one'>One</button>
<button id = 'two'>Two</button>
<script>
  var one = document.getElementById('one'),
    two = document.getElementById('two');
  let toggleForm = function(e) {
    if (e.target === one) alert('One');
    else alert('Two');
  };
  one.addEventListener("click", toggleForm, false);
  two.addEventListener("click", toggleForm, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome! I assume what's going on behind the screens is that inside addEventListener, an object (in our case 'e') get's passed into the callback?

Comment: Yes, e is the event object that gets passed to the listener. It has lots of other properties as well.

Comment: Very cool! Just did a console.log on the object and noticed the other properties. Thanks again